# Transportation: Minimizing Cost

Tags: integer-programming, network-flow

I am trying to solve this problem, but I have had no luck. I have tried to set this up in MS Excel, so I could use Solver to find the solution, but I don't really know how to form this problem. As far as I know, I calculate the Euclidean distance from 1 location to another and that tells me how much the cost of shipment is per unit ton of trash from one location to another. Then I am clueless...

[image]

Comment: You could enumerate all 1024 scenarios where to place a dump site. Each district can either have a dump site or not. This results in 1024 ways to place the dump sites. For every scenario, evaluate the costs by assigning trash to the least expensive dump site in terms of processing and transportation cost. If a dump site is overloaded, assign the trash to the next site.

Comment: @AxelKemper wait what :S how do I enumerate?

Comment: This is a facility location problem. When I have more time after work I'll write up a model and use an IP solver.

Comment: @Math1000 I can use Excel Solver to solve the IP, but how do I model this?

Comment: I will explain later today when I have time. Have to run to work now :)

Comment: The decision variables of your model are twofold: 1) binary variables per district (1=dump site, 0=no dump site), 2) 10 integer variables per district where to place how many tons of dump. The capacity limit is modelled as inequality. Non-existing dump sites have capacity 0. The cost function is a sum of transportation and processing costs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following untested [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) model tackles your problem:

```
% Number of districts
int: ndistricts = 10;
set of int: Districts = 1 .. ndistricts;

%  Coordinates
array[Districts] of int: x            = [  4,   2,  10,   2,   5,   4,  10,   5,   5,   1];
array[Districts] of int: y            = [  3,   5,   8,   8,   3,   5,   5,   1,   8,   7];

%  Distances between locations
array[Districts, Districts] of int: squared    
  = array2d(Districts, Districts, 
            [(x[i]-x[j])*(x[i]-x[j]) + (y[i]-y[j])*(y[i]-y[j]) | 
            i, j in Districts]);
array[Districts, Districts] of int: distance 
  = array2d(Districts, Districts, 
            [ceil(sqrt(int2float((squared[i, j])))) | 
            i, j in Districts]);

%  Dump tons
array[Districts] of int: tons         = [ 49, 874, 555, 352, 381, 428, 985, 105, 258, 210];
int: maxTons = 985;

%  Cost [million $]
array[Districts] of int: fixedCost    = [  2,   1,   1,   1,   3,   2,   1,   2,   4,   2];
array[Districts] of int: variableCost = [310,  40,  51, 341, 131, 182,  20,  40, 177,  75];
int: costFactor = 1000000;

int: costPerTonAndMile  = 1000;  % $
int: maxTonsPerDumpSite = 1500;

%  Variables
array[Districts] of var Districts: dumpTo;
array[Districts] of var bool: isDumpSite;

%  Constraints

%  dump tonnage has to stay below capacity
constraint forall (ds in Districts) (
  maxTonsPerDumpSite >= sum(d in Districts where dumpTo[d] == ds)(tons[d])
);

constraint forall (ds in Districts) (
  isDumpSite[ds] == (0 < sum(d in Districts where dumpTo[d] == ds)(1))
);

solve minimize sum(ds in Districts where isDumpSite[ds])(
%    fixed cost for dump site
     fixedCost[ds] * costFactor +
%    variable cost to transport dump to this site
     sum(d in Districts where dumpTo[d] == ds)(
        tons[d] * (distance[d, ds] * costPerTonAndMile + variableCost[ds])
     )
);

%  Solution

output ["\nDump allocation from District " ++ show(d) ++
        " to site " ++ show(dumpTo[d]) ++ ": " ++
        show(tons[d]) | 
        d in Districts 
];
```

The printed solution:

```
Dump allocation from District 1 to site 1: 49
Dump allocation from District 2 to site 3: 874
Dump allocation from District 3 to site 3: 555
Dump allocation from District 4 to site 2: 352
Dump allocation from District 5 to site 1: 381
Dump allocation from District 6 to site 1: 428
Dump allocation from District 7 to site 2: 985
Dump allocation from District 8 to site 1: 105
Dump allocation from District 9 to site 1: 258
Dump allocation from District 10 to site 1: 210
----------
==========
Finished in 119msec
```

Comment: that looks hardcore....I tried to type the model into Excel Solver and it took me about 4 hours and I got kind of the wrong solution :S

Comment: It should not take 4 hours to solve this problem. My model has 110 binary variables and 110 constraints. Any modern IP solver will be able to handle this with no problem (as you see from above, "Finished in 119msec").

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ be the set of districts. Define the decision variables
$$s_i = 
\begin{cases}1,& \text{dump site opened in district $i$}\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
for $i\in\mathcal S$, and
$$t_{ij} =
\begin{cases}1,& \text{district $i$ sends waste to district $j$}\\
0,& \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
for $i,j\in\mathcal S$. We have the parameters
\begin{align}
D_{ij} &= \text{Distance between districts $i$ and $j$ ($D_{ii}=0$)},\\
F_i &= \text{Fixed cost of opening dump site at district $i$}, S\\
V_i &= \text{Variable cost of processing one ton of waste in district $i$}, i\in\mathcal S\\
W_i &= \text{Tons of waste at site $i$}.
\end{align}
We can model this problem by the following integer program:
\begin{align}
\min & \quad\sum_{i\in\mathcal S}F_is_i + \sum_{i,j\in\mathcal S}D_{ij}W_it_{ij} + \sum_{i,j\in\mathcal S}V_it_{ij} \tag 1\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \quad \sum_{j\in\mathcal S} t_{ij} = 1,\quad\forall i\in\mathcal S\tag 2\\
&\quad t_{ij}\leqslant s_j,\quad \forall i,j\in\mathcal S\tag 3\\
&\quad s_i\in\{0,1\},\quad \forall i\in \mathcal S\\
&\quad t_{ij}\in\{0,1\},\quad \forall i,j\in\mathcal S.
\end{align}

We want to minimize the total cost, which is reflected in the objective function $(1)$. The first sum is the fixed cost of opening dump sites. The second sum is the cost of transporting waste. The third sum is the cost of processing waste.

Constraints $(2)$ ensure that every district sends its waste to exactly one district.

Constraints $(3)$ ensure that waste cannot be sent to a district unless a dump site is opened there

Comment: As for solving this problem, Excel is not a good choice. There are various commercial software packages for optimization, such as CPLEX, Gurobi, Xpress, etc. as well as libraries like pymprog for Python, or lpSolve for R.

Comment: Your model can be simplified. Every district is restricted to send its dump to exactly one site. Therefore, it is enough to have just one decision variable (rather than 10) per district which models the dump target site.

Comment: That is true, but then those decision variables take values in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} instead of in {0,1}. I wanted to model this purely with binary variables :)